# How to set properly the loader path of velocity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, velocity

i would like that my velocityengine look for templates from a designed path.
i did this :

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
 <property name="velocityProperties">
   <value>
     resource.loader=class
     class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
     class.resource.loader.resourceLoaderPath=/mytemplates
   </value>
 </property>
```

but is still looking for templates in the classes folder.
any idea?

Comment: A link about [Velocity's Resource Loaders](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#resourceloaders) from the official doc (not using Spring).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As illustrated in the spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html?#view-velocity), you could try the following:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
  <property name="velocityProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="resource.loader">file</prop>
      <prop key="file.resource.loader.class">
        org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
      </prop>
      <prop key="file.resource.loader.path">${webapp.root}/WEB-INF/velocity</prop>
      <prop key="file.resource.loader.cache">false</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Alternately, you could declare these properties in a `velocity.properties` and specify that

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
  <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/velocity.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you, how did you define ${webapp.root}

Comment: How do you define ${webapp.root}?

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/email_templates/"/>
</bean>

<bean name="mailTest" class="com.crisil.web.MailTestController">
    <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This is a much better solution. It uses Spring's abstraction to avoid having to set Velocity properties.

Comment: One point to note though, the resources must be on the class path(i.e. in a source folder).  I could not load resources that were under WEB-INF.

Comment: Works where /email_tempates/ is the full package, i.e. 'com/foo/templates/'

Comment: under webcontainer or webapps email_templates folder

Comment: Using `value="classpath:email_templates"`seems to work in both _webapp_ and _unit tests_ cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Resource Loader as

```
org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank i manage to work wih that : with FileResourceLoader , i should put the whole absolut path ie c:\tomcat......\mytemplates  . With ClasspathResourceLoader its look for templates in the classes folder