# Configure Velocity to read template file outside of the classpath

Tags: java, spring, templates, velocity

I am trying to configure Velocity to read the template file from the filesystem as opposed to it reading it from the classpath. I can get it to read the template file from the classpath if i configure velocityEngine as:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean" 
          p:resourceLoaderPath="classpath:/com/myapp/test" 
          p:preferFileSystemAccess="false"/>
```

And put the templatefile.vm in the com.myapp.test package.

How can i change the above so that i can put the template file anywhere in the file system and access it. I tried this but it did not work.

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean" 
          p:resourceLoaderPath="c:\home\users\me\app\templates" 
          p:preferFileSystemAccess="true"/>
```

I tried to google to see if i can find the solution but most examples are for Spring MVC configuration. I am using a standalone Spring application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying file name using `file:` like that:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean" 
          p:resourceLoaderPath="file://c:\home\users\me\app\templates" 
          p:preferFileSystemAccess="true"/>
```

Here's why I think it should work. According to [this document](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.0-RC1/api/net-2.0/html/Spring.Template.Velocity~Spring.Template.Velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryObject~Members.html) when you set `PreferFileSystemAccess` to `true` it starts using `SpringResourceLoader`. `SpringResourceLoader` is very versatile, here's a [nice overview](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-loader-with-getresource-example/).

---

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342704/how-to-set-properly-the-loader-path-of-velocity) may be relevant.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know i could do that. I feel stupid now :)

Comment: If it doesn't work, please try solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342704/how-to-set-properly-the-loader-path-of-velocity